# Sony Spresense Camera Board

Tags: image, sony, raw, jpeg2000, spresense

I am working with a Sony Spresense camera board with an Arduino camera library. In the example code that is available in the Arduino library, we can take JPG images. Now I want to take some RAW images.

I do not want to convert the JPEG image to a RAW image, I want to take RAW images from the camera.

I tried to change the setStillPictureImageFormat from (CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_JPG) to (CAM_IMAGE_PIX_FMT_RGB565) the code started running but I couldn't find the image in the SD card.